# Session errors when accessing a development Rails app through VirtualBox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm developing a Rails 3 app on Ubuntu 10.10 and need to check the CSS and Javascript on IE7 and IE8, so I'm using VirtualBox and the images that [Microsoft provides](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en). I've gotten the images installed and running well - I can use IE7 and IE8 to access the internet and use sites just fine.

I can also access my development Rails app (running on Ubuntu) by visiting 10.0.2.2:3000 in each browser (not sure why that works and localhost doesn't, but oh well). Any GET on a page that doesn't require the user to be logged in renders as I'd expect it to.

What's wrong are the sessions - as near as I can tell, both IE7 and IE8 are both just completely ignoring sessions with the development app. Whenever I submit the login form I get an InvalidAuthenticityToken error, and sure enough, in Rails' error page, the values in the session and params don't match. I even set up a special route to automatically log in the visitor as a random user, but it doesn't work. I just downloaded and installed Firefox in one of the virtual PCs and it's having the same problem as the IEs are.

Everything works perfectly in Chrome/Firefox in Ubuntu, so it doesn't seem to be Rails, and apparently it's not IE. I suppose there's something I'm missing with VirtualBox, but I have zero experience with virtualization before today, so I don't even know how to begin troubleshooting it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: The cookie wasn't being set because I was visiting the app through the ip address (Rails' `:domain => :all` option for the cookie store apparently doesn't cover that eventuality). I pointed lvh.me to 10.0.2.2 in the hosts file in WinXP, and everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem on IE8, session cookies were turned off. My Rails app login worked after I turned session cookies to on via:

- Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Privacy tab > Advanced button > tick "Always allow session cookies"